# Can I just call boost_replace instead of search and replace

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have the following function (that work):

```
    boost::regex ex(REGEX_TAG);
    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> extend;
    std::string::const_iterator start, end;
    boost::match_flag_type flags;
    std::string value("");

    start = input.begin();
    end = input.end();
    flags = boost::match_default;
    // The question start here 
    while (boost::regex_search(start, end, extend, ex, flags))
      {
        try
          {
            value = boost::any_cast<std::string>(param.at(extend[1]));
          }
        catch (const boost::bad_any_cast& err) {}
        catch (const std::out_of_range& err){}
        input = boost::regex_replace(input, ex, value, boost::match_default | boost::format_first_only);
        value.clear();
        start = extend[0].second;
        flags |= boost::match_prev_avail;
        flags |= boost::match_not_bob;
      }
```

But I'm actually using two regex functions who I guess do a lot of similar stuff (finding the expression...).
Do you any idea to remove the `boost::regex_search` and get the same output

Edit:

I'm trying to parse a template file of django:

input: `{{ lastName }} : {{ firstName }}`

param is a map of string, boost::any   `const std::map<std::string, boost::any>&`

and REGEX_TAG:  `#define REGEX_TAG "\\{\\{ ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) \\}\\}"`

It's working, I'm just asking if I can remove the `boost::regex_search` since `boost::regex_replace` is also searching (I guess)

Comment: Please don't edit your question to try to bump it up. It achieves little and might [get it locked instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4409/)

Comment: It is very hard to answer this question without sample input and actual regex